# Enhancement bonuses and Base Attack Bonus

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I've been wondering about this. If you have a weapon with an enhancement bonus, does it add to your BAB to get an additional attack? I know that if you have a BAB of 4 and an enhancement bonus of 2 that you now have a BAB of 6.

Now my confusion: It says that every time you reach a +6 in an attack you get another attack +6/+1. So if you had a character that normally has a BAB of +4 would that character get the BAB of +7/+2 with the enhancement bonus of 3. You've reached the +6 requirement to get an extra attack but would you actually get it?

Answer (score 6):

### No, you don't.

**BAB** is ***Base*** *Attack Bonus*. Emphasis on ***Base***.

It is a raw value, that is only dependent on your levels.

When you add other values to the BAB to determine what your roll to hit something, you have your *Attack Bonus*. If you check your character sheet, the Weapons Section don't have a BAB, just an "Attack Bonus". Those are different things.

Weapon Enhacement Bonuses are only accounted to the latter.

Comment: Strictly speaking, while BAB *should* be based solely on level, some things can affect it – most notoriously *divine power*. Such things explicitly say so, though.

Answer (score 4):

No. Bonuses to attack and Base Attack Bonus (BAB) are not the same thing.  You *only* get 'extra attacks' (iterative attacks on a full attack action) from Base Attack Bonus as a special property of that stat, not a property of attack bonus in general.  BAB increases with level, HD, and the application of certain spells, but is not affected by enhancement bonuses on weapons or anything giving a bonus "on attack rolls".  Actual increases/changes/bonuses to your effective BAB are always spelled out clearly and specifically designated as affecting base attack bonus.

Comment: is there anything to increase BAB without leveling up?

Comment: @urando ask that as another question.  When you do, include whether or not temporary increases are ok and if there are any resource limits involved.